# Better procedure for 'recovering'an STM32F103C8T6?

Tags: stm32, debugging, eclipse

I have a STM32F103C8T6 (aka blue pill) and worked with it.

Sometimes - due a reason I don't understand - after debugging it (using Eclipse), the connection is lost and I cannot start a new debug session.

The only thing to do is the following time consuming procedure:

- Close Eclipse
- Start ST-Link Utility
- In the menu ST-LINK/Firmware Update, selecting  button Device Connect (to see if the ST Link stick can connect).
- In case of an error, reinsert it (Windows shows Unknown USB Device) and redo the previous step
- In case of no error, it shows the version: V2.J27.S6 STM32+STM8 Debugger
- Than on the STM32 I have to press and hold the reset button
- Select the menu option Target/Erase Chip
- Release the button (in time, otherwise repeating the previous step)
- Than the chip is erased.
- Than start Eclipse again and I can continue

This is already a very tedious operation... is there a better solution?
Or by what reason the debugging session causes the STM32 to lose the ability to start a new debugging session?

And even than in some cases I get the following error when trying to debug:

```
23:23:02 : Can not connect to target!
                  If you're trying to connect to an STM32W1xx device, please select Normal or HotPlug mode from Target->Settings menu.
                  If you're trying to connect to a low frequency application , please select a lower SWD Frequency mode from Target->Settings menu.
23:23:03 : No target connected
```

The Eclipse project configuration file fragment:

```
# use software system reset
reset_config none
set CONNECT_UNDER_RESET 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem of one of the questions, so I added it for other people's reference, since it is a non-trivial default:

When using the STM32CubeMX which I do, whenever a project is made, by default the following item is selected:

- SYS, Debug: No Debug

This causes that the following code is generated in HAL_MspInit:

```
__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_REMAP_SWJ_DISABLE();
```

As soon as the debugger passes this command (which is one of the first commands in HAL_Init which is called in main(), the debugger loses connection and even a new debug session cannot be started.

It can be easily fixed with setting to

- SYS, Debug: Serial Wire

(which is also called SWD: Serial Wire Debug, and is supported by ST Link 2).

This causes that the following code is generated in HAL_MspInit:

```
__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_SWJ_NOJTAG();
```

And debugging works as usual.